# iAd Banner Error "Too many instances of iAd"

Tags: ios7, xcode5, iad

I have an ad banner view on one my view controllers that acts as an instructional page for my game. When that view controller has been loaded multiple times I receive the following error.

```
WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.
```

I have searched this error on stackoverflow, read the responses but nothing has worked for me. I have read that you are meant to release the ad banner and then nil it etc. which I have and still am receiving this error. The code for my "viewWillAppear" and "viewWillDissapear" is below. Any help will be appreciated!

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

_adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
_adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
```

}

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

if (_adBanner != nil) {
    _adBanner.delegate = nil;
    _adBanner.hidden = YES;
    [_adBanner release];
    _adBanner = nil;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the iAd from its superview before setting it to nil:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (_adBanner != nil) {
        [_adBanner removeFromSuperview]; // <-new line

        _adBanner.delegate = nil;
        _adBanner.hidden = YES;
        [_adBanner release];
        _adBanner = nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried using this code and the same error showed up.

Comment: @user3752308 That's a shame, removing it from the superview is a common way to solve it. Are you getting roughly the same number of calls to both `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`?

Comment: Not sure how to check that, I am just so confused with this error... every other person with the issue seems to be fine with the usual diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for iAd that I am already using in my apps with no problems:

```
implementation ViewController
{
    ADBannerView *adView;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate=self;
    bannerIsVisible=NO;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing the `adBannerView` in the individual class, create it in the `AppDelegate`.

I put:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *adBanner;
```

in my `AppDelegate.h` and:

```
self.adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
```

in my `AppDelegate.m`

And then in the individual class I put:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *adBanner;
```

in the .h and in the .m I put:

```
{
    BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
}
```

right below the `@interface` and in the `@implementation` I put:

```
#pragma mark Ads




- (WTMAppDelegate *) appdelegate {
    return (WTMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"Retreieved Ad");
    [self bringBannerBack];

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

    [self moveBannerViewOffScreen];
}

- (void)bringBannerBack
{



    [self.adBanner setAlpha:1];
    [self.adBanner setNeedsDisplay];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    self.adBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 50, 320, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    [self.adBanner setAlpha:1];

}
//Move the banner off the screen.
- (void)moveBannerViewOffScreen
{

    [self.adBanner setAlpha:0];
    [self.adBanner setNeedsDisplay];
    _bannerIsVisible = NO;

}
```

and in the viewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{


    self.adBanner.delegate=nil;
    self.adBanner=nil;
    [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];


}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.adBanner = [[self appdelegate] adBanner];
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

    if (self.adBanner.bannerLoaded == NO){
        NSLog(@"NO initial banner loaded");
        [self moveBannerViewOffScreen];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Initial ad loaded");
        [self bringBannerBack];
    }

}
```